# How can I convert a csv file to lowercase or uppercase maintaining it's structure using powershell?

Tags: powershell, csv, uppercase, lowercase

I have a CSV file that with contents that needs to be converted to all lowercase

I have tried the code below but it doesn't maintain the CSV structure.

```
(Get-Content C:\_Scratch\export.csv).ToLower() | Out-File C:\_scratch\export.csv

$Init = Import-Csv C:\_Scratch\export.csv
```

Is there another option I can try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Get-Content` is going to give you string array.  Add the `-Raw` switch to read it in as a single string, and the `.toupper()` and `.tolower()` string methods should work on that.

```
(Get-Content C:\_Scratch\export.csv -Raw).ToLower() | Out-File C:\_scratch\export.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$TempContentArray = $NULL
$TempContent = $NULL
$TempContent = Get-Content C:\_Scratch\import.csv
Foreach ($Line in $TempContent)
{
    $TempContentArray += $Line.ToUpper()
}
$TempContentArray | C:\_scratch\export.csv
$Init = Import-Csv C:\_Scratch\export.csv
```

Comment: This doesn't retain the line endings so everything is concatenated on one line. Suggest in the ForEach that you simply use add-content to write out the line to the new file. Then there is no need for the $TempContentArray variable.